# Quick Basic Neutral Network Fitting Question - Unknown label type:

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, valueerror

Here's by neural net code. I've tried everything and it seems like it should properly fit but it keeps coming up with a "ValueError: Unknown label type:" error **Please help!**

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

X = [[32.1, 27.9, 4.2], [30.2, 28.2, 2.0], [32.5, 24.2, 8.3], [31.3, 29.0, 2.3], [31.7, 24.5, 7.2], [33.3, 28.0, 5.3], [28.7, 28.8, -0.1], [30.5, 24.0, 6.5], [30.9, 31.0, -0.1], [36.0, 35.7, 0.3], [30.4, 26.2, 4.2], [24.8, 27.6, -2.8], [26.3, 23.4, 2.9], [27.0, 30.1, -3.1], [27.0, 28.9, -1.9], [21.1, 29.6, -8.5], [27.3, 30.8, -3.5], [23.4, 33.1, -9.7], [26.8, 28.3, -1.5], [30.8, 24.2, 6.6], [23.0, 23.9, -0.9], [29.6, 36.1, -6.5], [27.7, 29.3, -1.6], [23.3, 30.6, -7.3], [24.5, 29.5, -5.0], [27.0, 25.0, 2.0], [28.1, 28.1, 0.0], [23.0, 25.8, -2.8], [32.4, 28.7, 3.7], [22.5, 32.6, -10.1], [19.1, 33.5, -14.4], [24.2, 27.5, -3.3]]

y = [60.0, 58.4, 56.7, 60.3, 56.2, 61.3, 57.5, 54.5, 61.9, 71.7, 56.6, 52.4, 49.7, 57.1, 55.9, 50.7, 58.1, 56.5, 55.1, 55.0, 46.9, 65.7, 57.0, 53.9, 54.0, 52.0, 56.2, 48.8, 61.1, 55.1, 52.6, 51.7]

clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1) #learn more about this line

clf.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: The `MLPClassifier` is used for classification, so `y` values should be integer target values representing class labels. Details here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html. You can try `MLPRegressor`:  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor

Comment: Is there a machine learning system (linear regression, logistic, KMeans, etc) in sklearn that allows you to predict floats?